# jQuery tablesorter sort on date-time not working properly

Tags: jquery, datetime, tablesorter

I am using the tablesorter plugin and need to sort a column which contains dates and times. Using the shortDate type, the column sorts on date, but not on time i.e.
Jan. 12, 2011 11:13 AM goes to the top of the table followed by Jan. 12, 2011 11:16 AM which should be the top placed item. It looks as if the sorting is on text and not on the date. I have tried using a custom parser as suggested on these pages but it didn't work. Can anyone suggest an example format for the date-times as written to screen in the table in order for a custom parser to successfully sort on date and time?

Here is the sql to format the date:

```
date_format(data_invio,'%b. %e, %Y %l:%i %p')
```

This is code (found on this site) that I tried for the custom parser:

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({ 
id: 'dateMS', 
is: function(s) { 
    // return false so this parser is not auto detected 
    return false; 
}, 

format: function(s) { 
    var d = Date.parse(s);
    if (isNaN(d)) {
       return -1;
    }

    return d;
}, 
// set type, either numeric or text 

type: 'numeric' 
});

    $("table#ElencoRicevuti")
    .tablesorter({
    dateFormat: 'YYYY-mm-dd HH:ii:ss',
    headers: 
            {
            0: {sorter: 'dateMS'},
            4: {sorter: false}
            }
        })
```

Comment: could you show your code? Just here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707840/date-sorting-problem-with-jquery-tablesorter - you can see solving the same problem

Comment: Thanks IgorM, I looked at the suggested page and got the sorting to work using the parser. Initially it didn't work because the date was enclosed by <p> tags in the table cell. Removing the <p> tags to leave <td>2011-01-12 11:13:26</td> got it working. I also tweaked the script to remove the .0 at the end of the date in the original script.

Answer (score 1):

I love jQuery and all that, but I haven't found a jQuery table sort plugin that works as good as kryogenixs storttable. http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/.

And the tablesortter plugin you are using hasn't been updated since 2008-03-17

The kryogenix has all sorts of custom sorts. 
See "Using custom date formats": http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/#dates

Comment: The table sorter you link to was released in April 2007, so March 2008 would be more recent ;)

Comment: My sorttable.js gets tweaked without earning a new release date relatively often :)