# jQuery tablesorter parser for datetime in MM.DD.YYYY HH:MI AM format

Tags: jquery

I am having a 4 column table in which the 2nd column is a date column with the following format "mm.dd.yyyy hh:mi am". The default tablesorter doesn't sort by date column correctly. I had to write my own parser in tablesorter but it is still not working for me. I am not sure if the regex used is correct or not and if anyone can point me the mistake in the code below? I would appreciate your help.

```
ts.addParser(
{
    id: "srsDate",
    is: function (s) {
        return /\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s(am|pm)/.test(s);
    },
    format: function (s) {
        s = s.replace(/\./g, " ");
        s = s.replace(/\:/g, " ");
        s = s.replace("am", "0");
        s = s.replace("pm", "1");
        s = s.split(" ");
        return $.tablesorter.formatFloat(new Date(s[0], s[1], s[2], s[3], s[4], s[5]).getTime() + parseInt(s[6]));
    },
    type: "numeric" 
});
```

And I call it like:

```
myapp.Sort = function () {
    $(myapp.config.tblHistory).tablesorter({ headers: { 1: { sorter: 'srsDate'} }, sortList: [[0, 0]] });
}
```

I referenced: [date Sorting Problem with Jquery Tablesorter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707840/date-sorting-problem-with-jquery-tablesorter) to build the new parser. The results of the sort is not working. It doesn't sort the data at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't use tablesorter myself, however have you considered using [`Date.parse(datestring)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)?

Your function could then just be:

```
ts.addParser({
    id: "srsDate",
    is: function (s) {
        return /\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s(am|pm)/.test(s);
    },
    format: function (s) {
        return Date.parse(s);
    },
    type: "numeric" 
});
```

This will return that date as a Unix timestamp in milliseconds.

If you want to return it as the number of *seconds*, simple divide the result of `Date.parse(s)` by 1000:

```
function: function (s) {
    return (Date.parse(s) / 1000);
}
```

Although either method is fine if you're simply sorting the data.

Comment: Jam, thanks for the response. The first solution fixed the issue.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could be of service.