# jQuery tablesorter parser for datetime in DD.MM.YYYY HH:MI in 24hour format

Tags: jquery, parsing, datetime, tablesorter

I found this thread:
[jQuery tablesorter parser for datetime in MM.DD.YYYY HH:MI AM format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561026/jquery-tablesorter-parser-for-datetime-in-mm-dd-yyyy-hhmi-am-format)

but i want to sort date times like so: 22/01/2012 23:43

how can this parser which is in AM/PM format be modified to do that:

`ts.addParser({
    id: "srsDate",
    is: function (s) {
        return /\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s(am|pm)/.test(s);
    },
    format: function (s) {
        return Date.parse(s);
    },
    type: "numeric" 
});`

or can this be done directly from the tablesorter by setting the dateFormat to something like:

```
$("table").tablesorter({
  theme : 'blue',
  dateFormat : "ddmmyyyy HH:mm", // set the default date format
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort UK/European date format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm(works both with and without hour) by defining
dateformat:"uk" like so:

```
$("#tableName").tablesorter({dateFormat: "uk"});
```

Comment: It looks like you might be mixing options from the original tablesorter and my [forked version of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/). My fork allows setting the [`dateFormat`](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) as `"ddmmyyyy"` whereas the original has will only accept `"uk"` or `"dd-mm-yy"`; but only my fork has a `theme` option.