# jQuery plugin Tablesorter sorts dates incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

I'm trying to use the jQuery plugin Tablesorter to sort date fields. Now the strange thing is that the sorting seems to partially work, it does rearrange the order the results are displayed, which shows that at the very least, the script is initialised.

[image: Example of the problem]

Now I don't understand why this would be the case, my HTML looks like this:

```
<link href="/themes/blue/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function ()
{ 
    $("#repairtable").tablesorter(
{ 
    sortList: [[1, 0]], 
    dateFormat : "ddmmyyyy",
    headers: { 1:{ sorter: "shortDate", dateFormat: "ddmmyyyy"} }
});
} 
);
</script>
<table id="repairtable" class="tablesorter">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
    <th>Date In</th>
    <th>Customer</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
   <td>48</td>
   <td>11/03/2013</td>
   <td>Rainhem Launderette</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>13</td>
   <td>10/01/2013</td>
   <td>IESA (Gunstones)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>14</td>
   <td>10/01/2013</td>
   <td>GVF</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>41</td>
   <td>08/03/2013</td>
   <td>Triumph</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>42</td>
   <td>08/03/2013</td>
   <td>Triumph</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>43</td>
   <td>08/03/2013</td>
   <td>Triumph</td>
</tr>   
<tr>
   <td>40</td>
   <td>07/03/2013</td>
   <td>RAG Collections Ltd</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>38</td>
   <td>06/03/2013</td>
   <td>WM Sinclair</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>39</td>
   <td>06/03/2013</td>
   <td>WM Sinclair</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>22</td>
   <td>05/03/2013</td>
   <td>IESA Weetabix B'Lat</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Clicking on the appropriate column headers does sort the order of the data stored in the cells, but it orders dates incorrectly. I am attempting to order them by day / month / year but it doesn't seem to do so. There is actually more data in the table than I have shown here, one date field is 25/02/2013 which should be higher than 10/01/2013 which is the second row in the screenshot I provided.

I am relatively new to web development and any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Actually it looks like your code does sort the column correctly ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/528/)), at least in the latest version of the script ([v2.7.12](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/)).

Comment: Hm, quite odd behaviour I saw with it. Ckersch's suggestion did the trick to format it by day-month-year correctly though (dateFormat="uk"). I imagine it works with the latest version because the code I wrote was based on the later versions documentation I was reading as I wrote it. It turns out I used an older version for some inexplicably stupid reason on my part! Anyway it's good to know it worked as I originally intended it to on the version I was reading the documentation for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The US has an odd date convention, in which dates tend to be written month/day/year, so it's sorting them like that.

Edit: There already exists that functionality in tablesorter. Use:

```
$("#tableName").tablesorter({dateFormat: "uk"});
```

From [this other question about tablesorter.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707840/date-sorting-problem-with-jquery-tablesorter)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the tablesort library has changed since 2010 (when that question was posted) with a few extra features. It's supposed to have an in-built parser that will parse dd/mm/yyyy formats simply by specifying the format in the dateFormat. I suspect I'm being stupid and using it incorrectly, but I can't see how.

Comment: <Edit> You're absolutely right, quite odd though as the dateFormat: "uk" was supposed to have been deprecated according to the documentation I read. Supposedly 2.0.23 onwards use the "ddmmyyyy" format and anything below uses different arguments, such as "uk" as you mentioned. Anyway you're right, it worked without a hitch. I got confused thinking 2.0.5 was a higher version than 2.0.23 because I'm an idiot. Anyway thanks a lot!

Comment: The above comments saved my so much time. I had been scratching my head why "uk" wasn't working when I needed the new format:

`$("#tableName").tablesorter({dateFormat: "ddmmyyyy"});`

Answer (score 0):

What I did was: in the plugin, around line 970, in the `ts.addParser` function, I changed the following code to the `else if` dateformats:

```
        if (c.dateFormat == "us") {
            // reformat the string in ISO format
            s = s.replace(/(\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{4})/, "$3/$1/$2");
        } else if (c.dateFormat == "uk") {
            // reformat the string in ISO format
            s = s.replace(/(\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{4})/, "$3/$2/$1");
        } else if (c.dateFormat == "dd/mm/yy" || c.dateFormat == "dd-mm-yy") {
            s = s.replace(/(\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{2})/, "$1/$2/$3");
            // I added the lines below for the format with full year format,
            // Note that I inverted the day and month in the final format so
            // when the string is converted to date, it converts it right
        } else if (c.dateFormat == "dd/mm/yyyy" || c.dateFormat == "dd-mm-yyyy"){
            s = s.replace(/(\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3");
        }
```