# Sorting time column with jquery tablesorter

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am using jquery tablesorter to add sorting to a table.  I'm having issues sorting a column with only hh:mm:ss in it.  The SQL query producing this data is basically a now() - datetime field then in SQL I format it to hh:mm:ss.  When sorting the column tablesorter does not appear to recognize the time format and as a result does not sort it correctly.  Is there a way to correct this so that the times are sorted correctly?

Sorting Example:
53:47:57
53:33:34
530:54:38
52:12:14
52:07:58
526:21:35
51:53:41
51:53:26
51:41:34

Answer (score 4):

Tablesorter has a built-in time parser ([missing docs](http://wowmotty.blogspot.com/2011/06/jquery-tablesorter-missing-docs.html#parsers)), try this:

```
$("table").tablesorter({
    headers: {
        0: { sorter: 'time'}
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#tableId").tablesorter({
    headers: { column Number: { sorter: 'shortDate'} }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I added what you provided, but now the column is not sortable at all.

 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function()
         {
   $("table").tablesorter({
    headers: { 10: { sorter: 'shortDate'} }
   });
                 }
  );
 </script>

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707840/date-sorting-problem-with-jquery-tablesorter

Comment: you can find the details in the above link

Comment: Yep I saw that link and tried correcting the example to match my hh:mm:ss format, but could not figure it out.