# JQuery Table Sorter failing on date pattern'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS'

Tags: jquery

Unable to sort the date pattern 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS' with jQuery table sorter. I tried the following parser as well

```
ts.addParser({
    id: "customDate",
    is: function (s) {
        //return false;
        //use the above line if you don't want table sorter to auto detected this parser                           //else use the below line.           
        //attention: doesn't check for invalid stuff            
        //2009-77-77 77:77:77.000 would also be matched            
        //if that doesn't suit you alter the regex to be more restrictive           
        return /\d{1,4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}.\d{1,3}/.test(s);
    },
    format: function (s) {
        s = s.replace(/\-/g, " ");
        s = s.replace(/:/g, " ");
        s = s.replace(/\./g, " ");
        s = s.split(" ");
        return $.tablesorter.formatFloat(new Date(s[0], s[1] - 1, s[2], s[3], s[4], s[5], s[6]).getTime() + parseInt(s[7]));
    },
    type: "numeric"
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is already available on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707840/date-sorting-problem-with-jquery-tablesorter)

Note that you need to add the custom-sorter to your local.js file to get the table sorter working :

```
$(function() {
    $("table").tablesorter({
        headers: {
            6: { sorter:'customDate' }
        }
    });
});
```