# Sort Date with Tablesorter

Tags: jquery, sorting, tablesorter

I am trying to figure out how I can sort a column with mm/dd/yy using jquery tablesorter.  I figure I have to set up a custom parser, but I am unsure how to do this or where to start.  My logic would be to sort yy first, then dd, then mm. Right now it is sorting, but not the correct way. Ex. When the table is Desc it has: 
1/14/15,
3/13/15,
4/6/15,
1/2/14

I need it to be:
4/6/15,
3/13/15,
1/14/15,
1/2/14, etc....

Comment: I think this has already been answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707840/date-sorting-problem-with-jquery-tablesorter

Comment: Thanks, I was able to find the answer a couple answers down on this page.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get the sorting correctly by adding

```
$("myTable").tablesorter({
   headers: { 4: {sorter:'shortdate'}}
});
```

Than adjusted the shortdate in tablesorter.js

Comment: I would not recommend modifying the code within the plugin unless you plan on *never* updating the plugin.